# Set screen orientation for a fragment manually

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to set screen orientation manually, however I have found only a way to do this while creating an activity, or settings it in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

However I need to set orientation for a specific fragment. I have the same activity but fragments are changed periodically. And for different fragments I need to set different screen orientation.

Is it possible ? Or there is only a way to move fragment to an Activity ?

Thanks

Comment: you don't set the orientation on fragments, you set it on the parent activity

Comment: @Zoe, that is really bad

Comment: no, it's by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the orientation for your Activities.

Comment: Shame on SDK. Thx for answer

Comment: no problem ..yes we have some its own standards and limitations.

Comment: Hello @atzcijhu feel free to accept as it clarify your problem doubt

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback in the activity from your fragment

Answer (score -1):

Can you make this changes on your fragment?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    int w = container.getWidth();
    int h = container.getHeight();
    view.setRotation(90);
    view.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
    view.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = w;
    lp.width = h;
    view.requestLayout();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: You can't set the orientation of a fragment like with an activity

Comment: And setting the actual width and height to match landscape or portrait **is not the same as setting the orientation**

Comment: Yeap you can't set orientation but you can rotation a view and fragments has own view. So you can rotate it on fragment class.